# How to pass OAuth in swift header. Twitter Api (Get trending hashtags)

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, header, postman

How to pass this OAuth with Twitter API (Get trending hashtags) in swift header programmatically?

**Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you use a library for oAuth that will handle all of this for you. I'm using [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift) in one of my projects and it is working very well. If you want to use it you will need to:

1. Install it. I will recommend you to use `CocoaPods` so you will need to create a text file called `Podfile` (if you don't have it right now) and add this text:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'YourAppTarget' do
    pod 'OAuthSwift', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

and then call:

```
pod install
```

If you don't have `CocoaPods` installed please check [CocoaPods website](https://cocoapods.org/)

2. Setting URL Schemes. Add an item to `URL Types` in the info tab of your target. You should replace `oauth-swift` by your application name.
   [image: URL Types tab]
3. Handle opening URLs in AppDelegate.
   In iOS earlier than iOS 13 you will need to add:

```swift
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey  : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  if (url.host == "oauth-callback") {
    OAuthSwift.handle(url: url)
  }
  return true
}
```

On iOS 13, `UIKit` will notify `UISceneDelegate` instead of `UIApplicationDelegate`, so you will need to implement this method in `UISceneDelegate`:

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
            return
        }
        if (url.host == "oauth-callback") {
            OAuthSwift.handle(url: url)
        }
}
```

4. then you are ready to authorize. You can place this code in a function called after pressing the login button. This code assumes that `self` is a view controller.

```swift
// create an instance and retain it
oauthswift = OAuth1Swift(
    consumerKey:    "********",
    consumerSecret: "********",
    requestTokenUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
    authorizeUrl:    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
    accessTokenUrl:  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
)
oauthswift.authorizeURLHandler = SafariURLHandler(viewController: self, oauthSwift: oauthswift)
// authorize
let handle = oauthswift.authorize(
    withCallbackURL: URL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/twitter")!) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let (credential, response, parameters)):
      print(credential.oauthToken)
      print(credential.oauthTokenSecret)
      print(parameters["user_id"])
      // Do your request
    case .failure(let error):
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }             
}
```

Just keep in mind that this `oauth-swift` from `URL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/twitter")` should match url scheme from step 2. Also remember to retain `oauthswift` so it won't dealocate itselfs to soon. You can add it as property to your view controller.

5. If you want to make a call to fetch some data from API you should sign your request:

```swift
oauthswift.client.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~") { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let response):
        let dataString = response.string
        print(dataString)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Just rember that this singing should be called after successfull authorization (it is mark as `// Do your request` in step 4).

Hope that you will be able to add this library to your app. Let me know if you have any problem with it.

The code in this answer is copied from the library's [How to](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift#how-to) section, but I've added some highlights from myself.